# php form still refreshing with ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, forms

this is my html form

```
<form action="" method="post" id="form">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name..." name="name"id="name"/>
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email..." name="email" id="email"/>
    <textarea placeholder="Message..." name="text" maxlength="255" id="text"></textarea>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <i class="form-err"><?php  echo $err; ?></i>
    <br />
    <button
        id="btn2"
        type="submit"
        name="submit"
        style="--clr: #6017e9">
        <span>Send</span><i></i>
    </button>
</form>
```

my php

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "myserver";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "myserverr";
    $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    $name=$_POST["name"];
    $email=$_POST["email"];
    $message = $_POST["text"];
    $querystamp =getOS() . " - " .getBrowser();
    $port =$_SERVER["REMOTE_PORT"];
    $date =date("d-m-Y = h:i:sa") ;
```

I tried this but I don't get where the error is.

```
$('form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = {
        name: $('#name').val(),   
        email: $('#email').val(),
        text: $('#text').val()
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'index.php',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType: 'application/json'
    })
});
```

Comment: Can you please specify what is your actual question or what error you are getting

Comment: Did you use the browser's Developer Tools to check for script errors?

Comment: After you fix the refreshing issue, next you'll want to read [Receive JSON POST with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866571/receive-json-post-with-php), because otherwise your PHP script won't be able to read what the AJAX request is sending to it

Comment: When i run your code, ajax is sent and page is not refreshing

Comment: Have you made sure your JS function actually gets triggered? Have you tried `$('#form')` instead of `$('form')`?

Comment: @brombeer `$('form')` will select a `<form>` tag. So that shouldn't be a problem. Most likely issues are other script errors causing the scripts not to run and not bind the event, or not execute the event handler, or possibly if the jQuery event handler code is placed earlier in the file than the `<form` element, and isn't inside a document.ready block, then the form element won't exist when it's executed, and then it won't bind the event for that reason. Without anything else to go on, I'd suspect one of those things as the probable cause.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for the insight, should've read the docs before commenting (not a jquery user) ;)

Comment: @brombeer No worries. TBF it's more about CSS selectors than anything to do with jquery specifically :-)

Comment: @NebojsaNebojsa you understood the problem well

Comment: @brombeer #form or form are not the problem

Comment: @ADyson no problems

Comment: @ZaidMalek bruh it's not supposed to refresh there is no need for specifying lol

Comment: @samucode No, you _do_ need to specify, because when we try it, it seems to work correctly, and doesn't refresh. So if you have a problem where it doesn't refresh, you need to go through the list of things I mentioned and see if one of those is occurring for you. Maybe there's a JS error. Maybe you bound the event too late. We can't tell, sitting here, without a [mre] of the issue. So yeah, Zaid is 100% correct - you need to be more specific. See also the [ask] guide if you require more assistance with framing your question.

Comment: Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/50t7povf/ - the code you've provided sends the AJAX request correctly, and doesn't refresh. Something must be different in your environment, as I've mentioned. So you've got to go and investigate what that is.

Comment: Do you have some errors in browser console and can you put this on some public page, share link with us and we will se the problem on that real live page

Comment: @NebojsaNebojsa as per Stackoverflow guidance, the OP is supposed to put all the necessary info into their question, not into external sites - those sites can change or disappear, which makes the question (and any answers) meaningless for future readers. That's why we don't accept or encourage such demos - or at least, not without _also_ adding relevant code and error info into the post.